# d3.js GeoJSON transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I have created two GeoJSON objects, and when I inspect the element I can see them both listed. I have looked through numerous transition tutorials on d3.js and am still lost as to how to draw one, then transition to the other.

I have tried to implement the exit().remove() function within the second geoJSON object, but have failed to make this work. I am very much lost, and cannot seem to make anything I have found work.

I understand that the code below is very basic, but all the things I have tried have failed beyond this point.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cartogram 1</title>
<style>
</style>
<svg width="100" height="2"></svg>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1500)
        .attr("height", 1500)

    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular();    

    var world1 = d3.json("world2.json", function (data) {

      svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)});

    var world2 = d3.json("goldatt2.json", function (data) {

      svg.selectAll("h")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("h")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)});    

    path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);


</script>
```

This has been changed to:

```
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1500)
        .attr("height", 1500)

    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()  

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    d3.json("world2.json", function (data) {

      svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
    });


    d3.json("goldq.json", function (data) {

      var sel = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data.features);

      sel.enter()
        .append("g")
        .append("path");

     sel.transition().duration(1000).attr("d", path)

     sel.exit().remove();


    });
```

Which results in the following: 
http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s1227289/world/lars.html

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the path once you've drawn it:

```
 var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

d3.json("world2.json", function (data) {

  svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
});

d3.json("goldatt2.json", function (data) {

  var sel = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data.features);

  sel.enter()
    .append("g")
    .append("path");

 sel.attr("d", path);

 sel.exit().remove();
});
```

A few general notes. There is no `h` element. In the code above, the order of execution is not guaranteed as `d3.json` is asynchronous. You need to make sure that it executes in the order you want yourself, for example by nesting the calls to `d3.json`.

Comment: But how then I do transition between the two objects? Is that hugely obvious? I have looked through a number of examples and have become even more confused.

Comment: Sorry if this is very obvious @Lars Kotthoff

Comment: In each case, you're passing in different data. This data determines what is drawn and thus you should get different paths. If you want to animate the transition, do something like `sel.transition().duration(1000).attr("d", path)`.

Comment: So making the changes this results in:
http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s1227289/world/test5.html
@Lars Kotthoff

Comment: It's not really going to work with a world map. There're too many paths and they're too detailed. The performance will be very bad.

Comment: If the original shape files were greatly simplified would the code work? It only has to be one transition @Larks Kotthoff

Comment: Yes. I would start with a smaller part though to prototype.